# Как посмотреть содержимое папок на через smbclient?

Tags: python, smtplib

Добрый день необходимо посмотреть что лежит в папке, на сервере для чтение файлов excel я использую

```
smbclient.register_session("255.255.255.255", username='user', password='qwerty12345')
with smbclient.open_file(f'//255.255.255.255/folder/Country_dict.xlsx',mode='rb') as reader:
            df_airports = pd.read_excel(reader)
```

Но как к примеру посмотреть какие файлы лежат папке folder?

Как получить названия всех фалов из папки folder?

Comment: папки или файлы? И что означает посмотреть?

Comment: Посмотреть что лежит в папке, все файлы @Эникейщик

Comment: берите по ссылку любой код и замените ".txt" на ".xlsx"

Comment: Мне нужен список всех фаловв папке folde @Эникейщик

Comment: @Эникейщик какое отношение имеет дубликат к этому вопросу? В нём SMB вообще никак не упоминается

Comment: @andreymal ах, тут еще логин-пароль. Так то просто вставить r'//255.255.255.255/folder" как путь и никакой разницы, сервер или локальный диск.

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня есть сомнения в том, что это сработает на линуксовом клиенте)

Comment: @andreymal ну вообще тогда симлинк сделать и все 

Answer (score 0):

Что то вроде этого

```
smbclient.register_session("255.255.255.255", username='user', password='qwerty12345')

s = smbclient.listdir('//255.255.255.255/folder/')
```

Comment: @andreymal ответ